# How to stop Firefox & Safari from prompting location services on each page load?

Tags: javascript, cookies, geolocation, local-storage, navigator

I am having an issue where users are being prompted to allow / block their location every time they navigate to a new page on my website. This isn't happening on Chrome but it is happening on Firefox  and Safari. I know that users can select to 'always remember' their selection, but is there a way to just not have it happen regardless of if they have selected this or not?

````
// Function to calculate the distance between two points
              function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
                const R = 6371; // Radius of the Earth in km
                const dLat = ((lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI) / 180;
                const dLon = ((lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI) / 180;
                const a =
                  Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
                  Math.cos((lat1 * Math.PI) / 180) *
                    Math.cos((lat2 * Math.PI) / 180) *
                    Math.sin(dLon / 2) *
                    Math.sin(dLon / 2);
                const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
                return R * c;
              }
              
              // Function to get the user's location
              function getUserLocation() {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    // enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    // maximumAge: 5000000000,
                    handleUserLocation,
                    handleLocationError
                  );
                } else {
                  displayBlockedLocation();
                }
              }
              
              // Function to handle errors when getting the user's location
              function handleLocationError(error) {
                if (error.code === error.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                  displayBlockedLocation();
                }
              }
              
              function handleUserLocation(position) {
                const userLocation = {
                  lat: position.coords.latitude,
                  lng: position.coords.longitude,
                };
              
                let nearestStore = null;
                let nearestDistance = Infinity;
              
                storeLocations.forEach((storeLocation) => {
                  const distance = calculateDistance(
                    userLocation.lat,
                    userLocation.lng,
                    storeLocation.lat,
                    storeLocation.lng
                  );
              
                  if (distance < nearestDistance) {
                    nearestDistance = distance;
                    nearestStore = storeLocation;
                  }
                });
              
                const distanceInMiles = nearestDistance * 0.621371;
              
                if (distanceInMiles <= 50) {
                  displayMessage(nearestStore, distanceInMiles);
                } else {
                  displayBlockedLocation();
                }
              }

              // Function to display the blocked location message
              function displayBlockedLocation() {
                  ...code
              }

              // Function to display a message in the header
              function displayMessage(storeDetails, distanceInMiles) {
                  ...code
              }

              // Call the getUserLocation function to initiate the process
              getUserLocation();
    ```
````

Comment: This is a security feature, it wouldn't make sense for applications to be able to bypass it. I think Chrome remembers it per site, it sounds like FF remembers the selection per page.

Comment: I feel like there must be a way, though, because I try other websites that prompt me to allow my location and I'll allow it and navigate around the site and I'm not asked again even though I didn't check the option to remember my selection.